# I want to set "Password Must Change at Next Login" flag

Tags: c#, active-directory

In my application, I am doing things that a user can control his/her local Windows User account from my app i.e. creating user, set/remove password, change password and also invoking password expiration policy is possible from my app. Now, at this point, I need to figure out If user wants to change his password at next login, then what happens. As many forums and blogs say about this, I did coding accordingly:

**Invoke Password Expire at Next Login**

```
 public bool InvokePasswordExpiredPolicy()
    {
        try
        {
            string path = GetDirectoryPath();
            string attribute = "PasswordExpired";
            DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(path);
            de.RefreshCache(new string[] { attribute });
            if(de.Properties.Contains("PasswordExpired"))
            de.Properties[attribute].Value = 1;
            de.CommitChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Provoke Password Expire at Next Login. Reset the flag**

```
public bool ProvokePasswordExpiredPolicy()
    {
        try
        {
            string path = GetDirectoryPath();
            string attribute = "PasswordExpired";
            DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(path);
            de.RefreshCache(new string[] { attribute });
            de.Properties[attribute].Value = -1;
            de.CommitChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Checking for whether concerned flag is set or not**

```
public bool isPasswordPolicyInvoked()
    {
        try
        {
            string path = GetDirectoryPath();
            string attribute = "PasswordExpired";
            DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(path);
            de.RefreshCache(new string[] { attribute });
            int value = Convert.ToInt32(de.Properties[attribute].Value);

            if (value == 1)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I am using WinNT to get the directory path rather than LDAP. I used the following method to **get the directory path.**

```
private String GetDirectoryPath()
    {
        String uName = this.userName;
        String mName = this.userMachine;

        String directoryPath = "WinNT://" + mName + "/" + uName;

        return directoryPath;
    }
```

is there anything I am missing? Help me out here.

**Note:** Firstly, I used **pwdLastSet** attribute to be set to 0(for on) and -1(for off) that throws an exception "Directory Property Not found in Property Cache", later I discovered that WinNT doesn't support this attribute rather it supports **PasswordExpired** which needs to be 1 to set the flag. That's what I did.

Answer (score 8):

How about using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement instead, in which case you can call the following code:

```
UserPrincipal.Current.ExpirePasswordNow();
```

Comment: What does it do? When you set a temporary password, does it ask the user to change it when they login with the tempory password?

Answer (score 6):

The code below should work:

```
de.Properties["pwdLastSet"][0] = 0;
```

From [User Must Change Password at Next Logon (LDAP Provider)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746510(VS.85).aspx):

> To force a user to change their password at next logon, set the pwdLastSet attribute to zero (0). To remove this requirement, set the pwdLastSet attribute to -1. The pwdLastSet attribute cannot be set to any other value except by the system.

Answer (score 1):

I tracked this down. This corresponds to the `UserPrincipal.LastPasswordSet` property.

The property is read only so you have to set using these methods:

```
    public bool UserMustChangePasswordNextLogon
    {
        get
        {
            return (_userPrincipal.LastPasswordSet == null);
        }
        set
        {
            if (value)
                _userPrincipal.ExpirePasswordNow();
            else
                _userPrincipal.RefreshExpiredPassword();
        }
    }
```

In my case I set variables to expire or refresh the password on next save instead of in the property setter.

Answer (score -3):

```
de.Properties["passwordExpired"][0] = 1; <br>
de.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: Define this
  private const Int32 PASSWORD_EXPIRED = 0x800000;

OR it into your user account control. Sorry no code, my method is part of a highly abstracted library, and wouldn't make much sense.